# How can I create a function to read structure variables from a file and compare string dates?

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a function that reads a primary key from a structure array to further compare two corresponding variables in the structure that stores the date (Members[x].expdate and the current date) to output a result "Expired" if the current date is greater than the expiration date, Members[x].expdate and "Valid" otherwise. Can someone show me exactly how I would do so?

This is the structure, "ssn" is the primary key.

```
struct MembershipInfo_t
{
char ssn[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];
int   set;
unsigned payplan;
char  cust_fname[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
char  cust_lname[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
char  memtype[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
char  date[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
char selection[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ][10];
char status[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
char  expdate[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];
};
```

A separate function prompts the user for the above and stores it on a DAT file.

This is what I have so far of the function that is supposed to determine validation

```
void MemberExp()
{

FILE *Membership;

Membership= fopen("MembershipRecord.DAT", "rb");


printf("Please enter social security number\n");
scanf( "%s" , ssncheck);
fscanf(Membership, "%s", Members[x].ssn);

if(strcmp(ssncheck, Members[x].ssn)==0){



}





fclose(Membership);
}
```

Can you help me to create the function that carries out the above?

To remove ambiguity, the function that prompts the user for the information puts this on the file for example:

```
John    Daley
Platinum Membership
You have all services available
SSN: 123-456-789
The Full cost is $ 1230
19 January 2016
Expiration Date: 19 February 2016




Ron John
Platinum Membership
You have all services available
SSN: 223-456-789
The Full cost is $ 1230
19 January 2016
Expiration Date: 19 March 2016
```

The function I wish to create would identify the record using the SSN, so if I were to type 223-456-789 I would access the structure array with all the data for Ron John. If I were to type 123-456-789, I would access the structure array with all the data for John Daley. 
Then it would get the expiration date for whichever member I wanted to access using their SSN and compare it with the current date. Again, if the current date exceeds Members[x].expdate,which in the case of John Daley is the 19th of February, it would display "expired" or "Valid otherwise"

Comment: What you should do is to load (read) all structs from `MembershipRecord.DAT` into an array before asking the user to enter the `ssn`. (that can be done in a separate function) That way all structs are held in memory and you can simply loop over each of the elements and compare `ssn` values. Otherwise, you will have to read through the file each time the user enters a `ssn` which is orders-of-magnitude slower than reading from memory.

Comment: BTW: in the U.S.A. an ssn is 3digits-2digits-4digits not 3digits-3digits-3digits.  And certain ssn values will have an additional 10 character (for railroad employees, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare dates, you can use `difftime()` function; first convert the dates to a correct format by `strptime()`:

```
bool check_expired(const char *date, const char *expdate)
{
    struct tm tm_date, tm_expdate;

    if (strptime(date, "%d %b %Y", &tm_date) == NULL
        || strptime(expdate, "%d %b %Y", &tm_expdate) == NULL) {
        // wrong format, count as expired
        printf("strptime failed\n");
        return true;
    }

    return difftime(mktime(&tm_date), mktime(&tm_expdate)) < 0;
}
```

To compare records, for performance reasons the best idea usually is to read the file once and then keep all the records in memory, in an array.

If it is not possible or not desired, this logic should work: read the file line-by-line. Keep a current record and fill it until all fields have been filled. Then do the SSN check; it it matches, compare the dates and break the file-reading loop. Assuming a record is always 6 non-empty lines:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// ...

void member_exp()
{
    FILE *membership;
    struct MembershipInfo_t member;
    char line[256];
    char ssncheck[20];
    char tmp1[20], tmp2[20];
    int record_line = 0;

    membership = fopen("MembershipRecord.DAT", "rb");

    printf("Please enter social security number\n");
    if (scanf("%20s", ssncheck) != 1) {
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), membership)) {
        // check if the line is whitespace only
        char *p = line;
        bool is_spaces_only = true;
        while (*p) {
            if (!isspace(*p)) {
                is_spaces_only = false;
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if (is_spaces_only) {
            continue;
        }

        switch (record_line) {
        case 0:
            sscanf(line, "%s %s", member.cust_lname, member.cust_fname);
            break;
        case 1:
            sscanf(line, "%s", member.memtype);
            break;
        case 2:
            // TODO
            break;
        case 3:
            sscanf(line, "SSN: %s", member.ssn);
            break;
        case 4:
            // TODO
            break;
        case 5:
            sscanf(line, "%20s %20s %20s", member.date, tmp1, tmp2);
            strcat(member.date, " ");
            strcat(member.date, tmp1);
            strcat(member.date, " ");
            strcat(member.date, tmp2);
            break;
        case 6:
            sscanf(line, "Expiration Date: %20s %20s %20s", member.expdate, tmp1, tmp2);
            strcat(member.expdate, " ");
            strcat(member.expdate, tmp1);
            strcat(member.expdate, " ");
            strcat(member.expdate, tmp2);
            break;
        }

        record_line++;
        if (record_line > 6) {
            if (!strcmp(member.ssn, ssncheck)) {
                printf("record found. it is %sexpired\n",
                        check_expired(member.date, member.expdate) ? "not " : "");
                break;
            }
            record_line = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(membership);
}
```